# Why can't this class find this array?

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array which works in the first class (**ColoredWordsExperiment**), while the second class, (**ButtonHandler**), cannot find it.

The strange thing is that if I, in the **ButtonHandler** class, substitute **coloredWords.labels[i]** or let's say "coloredWords.labels[1]" for simply **coloredWords.labels1**, while in the first class I declare `JLabel labels1 = new JLabel;` it works.

That's basically what I initially had but since I have 12 labels I decided to use an array instead. The problem now is that the class ButtonHandler cannot find the variable "coloredWords.labels[i]".

This is the code (I left out unimportant stuff otherwise the code would be quite long):

```
public class ColoredWordsExperiment {
    ButtonHandler buttonHandler;

    ColoredWordsExperiment(){
        JLabel[] labels = new JLabel[12];
        for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        labels[i] = new JLabel("Press Button");
        labels[i].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(90,40));
        labels[i].setOpaque(true);
        labels[i].setBackground(Color.white);
        labels[i].setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        labelContainer.add(labels[i]);
        }

    button1 = new JButton("Matching");
    buttonHandler = new ButtonHandler(this);
    button1.addActionListener(buttonHandler);
    }

    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        new ColoredWordsExperiment();
    }
}
```

-

```
class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener {
    ColoredWordsExperiment coloredWords;
    public ButtonHandler(ColoredWordsExperiment coloredWords) {
        this.coloredWords = coloredWords;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Matching")) {
        for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            coloredWords.labels[i].setText("Text changed");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Definitely not going to help. Please show how you have used the class.

Comment: How you have made the objects of the class? Is the labels array been initialized?

Comment: @Nabin the class is being used inside `main` method. You can follow the code with no problem. If not, use an IDE.

Comment: your variable Jlabel is inside of the constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JLabel[] labels` is a variable declared inside the constructor of your `ColoredWordsExperiment` class. Move this as a field in the class and initialize it in your class constructor:

```
public class ColoredWordsExperiment {
    ButtonHandler buttonHandler;
    //it should be declared here
    JLabel[] labels;

    ColoredWordsExperiment() {
        //this is a variable inside the class constructor
        //JLabel[] labels = new JLabel[12];
        //this line initializes the labels field
        labels = new JLabel[12];
        // rest of your code...
    }
}
```

Also, you should declare a getter method to obtain one of the `JLabel`s inside the `labels` variable instead of using a direct access to this variable. This will make your code cleaner.